# Save online team site as Template (without content) will preserve site pages but not lists items

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, site-template, team-sites

I am working on a classic online team site. and i have a subsite which contain these main components:-

1. 3 custom lists which contain items.
2. i added many modern site pages inside the built-in sitePages library. and i set one of the modern pages as the home page for the subsite.

now i saved the sub-site as template, and i chose not to include the content. then i created a new sub-site based on the templete, but i found that the new sub-site which i created based on the templete, will contain empty custom lists (which make sense since i chose not to include content inside the site template), while it will contain the modern pages inside the SitePages library + the home page which i set is also preserved.

**so can i conclude that site templates which is created without content, will always include site pages, but will not include custom list items?**

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: Since 'Site Pages' is a default app in a team site, it seems logical that items in that location would be saved automatically (even when choosing not to include content). Perhaps further testing with items in other default locations, (i.e. Shared Documents, Calendar) could further your testing?

Comment: @DrewPaxton as per my test, documents inside the Shared Documents library will not be included in the site template unless saving content checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Site Pages and their associated files to run them are always included in a site template. The files located in libraries and the content inside of any lists will not be saved unless you direct the template to do so. Therefore, your conclusion is correct.

Comment: but i am not sure if any file inside a library will be included in the site template which is saved without content. Take a document library as an example,  the documents inside it will not be included in the site template unless the site content is shown to be saved inside the site template...